# Android Web View not loading this static Html

Tags: android

I have a html string which loads fine in browser but when trying to load in andriod web view it shows blank screen without any error. I donot want to load via file url as i want the params in this string to be dynamic.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private ProgressDialog  prg;
    private  WebView webView;
    private  int counter=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String htmlString = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
                "<html>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "<head>\n" +
                "  <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n" +
                "  <title></title>\n" +
                "  <meta name=\"author\" content=\"\">\n" +
                "  <meta name=\"description\" content=\"\">\n" +
                "  <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\n" +
                "\n" +
                "  \n" +
                "</head>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "<body>\n" +
                "\n Hello" +
                "<my-component source-url=\"https://fcc3ddae59ed.us-west-2.playback.live-video.net/api/video/v1/us-west-2.893648527354.channel.DmumNckWFTqz.m3u8\"/>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "<script src='https://unpkg.com/rahulrsingh09-stenciltest2@0.0.3/dist/test/test.js'></script>\n" +
                "</body>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "</html>";
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getPath());
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadData(htmlString, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");;
    
    }


    public void getWebview(String myurl)
    {

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                prg.show();
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                prg.dismiss();

                view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }


            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

        });
        prg = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Blog App", "İçerik Yükleniyor", true);
        webView.loadUrl(myurl);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }


}
```

What is the issue here can some one point it to me ?

**Edit**

[image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below -> Issue with base url not provided.

```
public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {


    private ProgressDialog prg;
    private WebView webView;
    private int counter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String htmlString = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
                "<html>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "<head>\n" +
                "  <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n" +
                "  <title></title>\n" +
                "  <meta name=\"author\" content=\"\">\n" +
                "  <meta name=\"description\" content=\"\">\n" +
                "  <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\n" +
                "\n" +
                "  \n" +
                "</head>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "<body>\n" +
                "\n Hello" +
                "<my-component source-url=\"https://fcc3ddae59ed.us-west-2.playback.live-video.net/api/video/v1/us-west-2.893648527354.channel.DmumNckWFTqz.m3u8\"/>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "<script src='https://unpkg.com/rahulrsingh09-stenciltest2@0.0.3/dist/test/test.js'></script>\n" +
                "</body>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "</html>";
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_web);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        settings.setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getPath());
        settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://fcc3ddae59ed.us-west-2.playback.live-video.net", htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
        
    }

    public void getWebview(String myurl) {

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                prg.show();
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                prg.dismiss();
                view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

        });
        prg = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity2.this, "Blog App", "İçerik Yükleniyor", true);
        webView.loadUrl(myurl);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Check its working]

Comment: I donot want to load via a url but via string

Comment: @INFOSYS its via HTML string only but you need to provide the **BASE_URL** . Its working as you wanted.

Comment: why is this base url required can you please shed some light there ? seems odd as this is a local string

Comment: @INFOSYS  I have edited to provide full activity code for you. Check & run this.

Comment: @user8608556 can you please highlight why we need base url any reason for the same ?

Comment: @INFOSYS Please refer https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating

Comment: seems a bit vauge can you please pin point.. will be really helpful

Comment: @INFOSYS Here you go https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating#URLs There has been changes to WebView since 4.4 which makes providing base URL.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlString , "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

it should work now

user8608556 answer is correct
If you don't want  video url as base url incase dynamic  , try to provide your script url as base url

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://unpkg.com/rahulrsingh09-stenciltest2@0.0.3/dist/test/test.js", htmlString , "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: still gives me the white screen please find the image attached above @aryanagarwal

Comment: @INFOSYS ok I will check

Comment: @INFOSYS recheck this

Comment: Yes I also mentioned that in my answer , user one should be the accepted one

Comment: what I meant to say was the different url , nothing else

Answer (score 0):

If you know the html you can create a html file. In your app>src>main directory create a directory called "assets". Within this directory place the html file which is correctly formatted, call this webViewfile.html etc

Then from your web view you can load it in as so

```
    webPlayerWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/webViewfile.html")
```

with your html file contexts to be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="author" content=""/>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0;">
<my-component source-url="https://fcc3ddae59ed.us-west-2.playback.live-video.net/api/video/v1/us-west-2.893648527354.channel.DmumNckWFTqz.m3u8"></my-component>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rahulrsingh09-stenciltest2@0.0.3/dist/test/test.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tested this and it works